# For Loop is not looping untill the given range in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

```
sleep till Rest api
  FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    20
    Sleep    5s till rest api is available
    ${result} = Check Rest Api 
    Exit For Loop If    ${result} == True        
    Log to Console  try again in 5 sec 
  END
```

I am using For loop to sleep for some time until the api is available and exit from loop once it has got the response. For this I had stored the result of the keyword in a varibale and gave exit from loop when result becomes true. But, whats happening is first it waits for 5 seconds and checks the result and fails. After failing once it is not iterating and fails at checking the result itself.

Here when it goes through the second line in for loop ( ${result} = Check Rest Api ). The sleep time is not sufficient and it fails at that statement itself. What I am expecting is the loop should continue until it gets the response.

Comment: Issue might be in what ´Check Rest Api` returns. Are you sure it returns False if API is not ready?

Comment: are you return boolean or string ?

Comment: def check_rest_api(self):
        try:
           r = requests.get("http://example.com")
           return True
        except ConnectionError as e:    
           print ("e")
           return False                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                       
      The get request here is an example. The actual response what i need cannot get in 5 sec and it fails without looping untill the response is true.